# Partial change on parent hover, full change on element hover

Tags: html, css, user-interface, hover

I'd like to have a UI element fade in slightly when hovering on its parent div, then fade in completely when hovering on the UI element itself. But it seems that if I set the parent hover, hovering on the child doesn't do anything.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div> <!-- end child -->
</div> <!-- end parent -->
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

/* fades in partially, looks nice */
#parent:hover #child {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

/* doesn't seem to do anything! */
#child:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/1khjo42q/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a specificity issue. The `#parent:hover #child` selector is "winning out" over `#child:hover`. Change the second to `#parent:hover #child:hover` (or just `#parent #child:hover`), and you should be set. https://jsfiddle.net/1khjo42q/1/

Comment: Super, thanks! I figured it was something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the rule `#parent:hover #child` has higher priority than `#child:hover` because it describes more elements in the DOM tree.

For increasing the priority of `#child:hover` there are two ways:

1. Describe it more precisely with

```css
    #parent #child:hover
```

2. Add `!important` to `opacity: 1`:

```css
    opacity: 1 !important;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1khjo42q/2/)

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

#parent:hover #child {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#parent #child:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div> <!-- end child -->
</div> <!-- end parent -->
```

PS: You might also want to add a [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Answer (score 0):

Add transitions

```
#child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
  /* added these */
  -webkit-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
  transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
}
```